# How to call :mimemail in Elixir?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

[antp/mailer](https://github.com/antp/mailer) calls `:mimemail.encode` in [mailer/smtp_client.ex](https://github.com/antp/mailer/blob/master/lib/mailer/smtp_client.ex#L3). It works correctly if it runs within `mix phoenix.server`, but it fails to call it in a release environment(built with `mix release`). It crushes with the following error:

```
(UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function :mimemail.encode/1 (module :mimemail is not available)
```

Is there any configuration to call it in exrm env, or miss something to configure?

[Updates]
`application` and `deps` in my mix.exs is below:

```
 def application do
    [mod: {NeoSmslife, []},
     applications: [:phoenix, :phoenix_html, :cowboy, :logger, :gettext,
                    :phoenix_ecto, :mariaex,
                    :logger_file_backend,
                    :tzdata,
                    :ueberauth,
                    :ueberauth_facebook,
                    :ueberauth_twitter,
                    :timex,
                    :guardian,
                    :mailer,
                    :secure_random
                  ]]
  end

 defp deps do
    [{:phoenix, "~> 1.1.2"},
     {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 2.0"},
     {:mariaex, ">= 0.0.0"},
     {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.3"},
     {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.0", only: :dev},
     {:gettext, "~> 0.9"},
     {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"},
     {:logger_file_backend , "~> 0.0.5"},
     {:secure_random, "~> 0.2"},
     {:mailer, github: "antp/mailer"},
     {:guardian, "~> 0.9.0"},
     {:guardian_db, "0.4.0"},
     {:ueberauth, "~> 0.2"},
     {:ueberauth_facebook, "~> 0.3.2"},
     {:oauth, github: "tim/erlang-oauth"},
     {:ueberauth_twitter, "~> 0.2"},
     {:timex, "~> 1.0.1"},
     {:mix_test_watch, "~> 0.2", only: :dev},
     {:exrm, "~> 1.0.2"}

   ]
  end
```

Comment: Post your mix.exs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding [gen_smtp](https://hex.pm/packages/gen_smtp) to your dependencies and applications list. I'm not sure why it would work without that dependency on a non-release version; I mean I believe you should get that error either way without gen_smtp specified.

Comment: It worked correctly with appending `gen_smtp` into applications and deps. Thank, you!